# Performance problems - Jira running on Ubuntu over VMware ESX 4.0 maxing out all 4 vCPUs

Tags: java, vmware-esx, jira

We are running Jira on a box under VMware ESX 4.0 and performance is vaiable to say the least. The physical box has 12 Gig RAM and 4x Xeon 2.26 GHz CPUs. vCentre is telling us the CPUs are not maxed out at any time, RAM is fine too. When we issue a request to the host it sometimes maxes out all 4 vCPUs. Sometimes it's quick, sometimes very very slow. There doesn't seem to be a pattern.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using mysql as your backend.. or their hqsql i think it is..

Answer (score 1):

Turned out they were Tunneling in over SSH (using putty SSH port forwarding ). I got them to VPN into our firewall instead and when they connected in via normal HTTP it worked just fine!

Java having issues with SSH decrypt? Who knows. Working now.

Comment: Please mark this as the solution to your question

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like the heap memory issue. I think jira allocated 128M of RAM to run on.

So in

```
./bin/setenv.sh
```

Just increase the memory options for

```
JAVA_OPTS
JIRA_MAX_PERM_SIZE
```

Then restart jira.. see if that helps. That is what helped for me on slow page/ajax loads.